# How to use css transition on child element while dynamically changing parent class?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

http://jsfiddle.net/833X6/

As you can see in the above fiddle, I am using bootstrap, and I want the navbar to always stay in view, so on scrolling down a bit, I add the `navbar-fixed-top` class to it, and as soon as this class is added, I want a child text to fade in using css transition. For that I tried:

```
.navbar .menuItem-cart{
    opacity:0;
    transition:all 5s ease-in;
}
.navbar.navbar-fixed-top .menuItem-cart{
    opacity:1;
}
```

But this doesn't seem to work, however if I change the opacity value of `.menuItem-cart` manually in firebug, the transition does kick in. What am I doing wrong?

PS: I didn't include all the browser specific transitions as I am still testing this in the latest firefox.

Answer (score 2):

The CSS `transition` property does not inherit: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition-property

So you'd need to apply a transition property to your child element separately.

UPDATE:

I misread your initial CSS, apologies. Yes, that *should* work!

Alas, I can not figure out why it won't work in Firefox. I've tried a number of variations of class assignments, changing specificity, and even changing what we're transitioning but your JSfiddle, in Firefox, never actually animates the transition. It just 'snaps' into final state.

So I'm stumped. I really hope someone else can answer this.

BTW, if you google 'CSS transition problems in Firefox' you'll note a lot of issues posted on StackExchange. Alas, each question seems to have a different answer.

At this point, I'd suggest trying to build a sample JSFiddle sans the bootstrap CSS. It could be that there is some CSS in there that is messing with our own CSS in terms of specificity and the like. That'd at least narrow the issue down.

As for IE...at least I can answer that. If we're talking IE8 and older, the issue is that it doesn't support CSS `opacity`. You'd have to use an IE filter for that: `filter: alpha(opacity=70);` I don't know if you can CSS transition IE8's filters.

Comment: But it works properly in IE and Chrome, so how exactly do I fix it in Firefox?

Comment: Sorry but I didn't quite understand what you meant, since the style is being changed for the same class. Can you please make a fiddle or some example to explain a bit more

Comment: @user279988 ah! Apologies! I think I misread your CSS. I'll update my answer.

Comment: @user279988 answer updated. I'm stumped. I spent a half hour on it and can not figure out what is going on in Firefox. I wish you luck and hope someone else can shed some light on this mystery! I'm curious now!